# How can I extract info from list of dictionaries within a dataframe column?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary, slack

I pulled this data from slack, and I need to be able to access the information within this column called Blocks, I would like to be able to extract the information from user id, summary, ticket number, and company name, but am not sure how to do this. I would like to write a function that extracts this information, and puts them into new columns in the dataframe with their respective key names, such as user id, summary, company name, and ticket number.

The second photo is an entire row value from the blocks column, I just had to cover company name, user name, etc. for security.

[image: This is the first row of dataframe after converting json to dataframe, blocks column is column in question]

[image: blocks column with list of dictionaries]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  If your question include a pandas dataframe, please provide a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @ChelseaSupencheck add a value from the blocks column to the question.

Comment: the second photo is an entire row value from blocks column, I covered identifying info for security, but that is the info I want to extract